How to split chunks into individual JSON objects
I am fetching from an api which sends data in a stream. Unfortunately when I process the data in chunks, the chunks come as multiple JSON strings like this;
         { 
           "productName": "bag",
           "code": "BGX-112"
         } 
         { 
           "productName": "purse",
           "code": "PUSR-112"
         } 
         etc..



Here is the code that process the data:

            const getProductData = async (url:string) => {
               const decoder = new TextDecoderStream()
               let chunks: any[];
               chunks = [];
               try {
                   const response = await fetch(url)
                   const stream = response?.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream());
                   const reader = stream.getReader()
                   while (true) {
                       const {value, done} = await reader.read();
                       if (done) {
                           // Flush any buffered characters.
                           const stringArray = value?.split(/\b\s/);
                           chunks.push(value);
                           return chunks;
                       }
                       if (value) {
                           const stringArray = value?.split(/\b\s/);
                           chunks.push(value);
                       }
        
                   }
               }catch (e) {
                   console.error("Error ",e)
               }
           }




I want to get the chunks as individual JSON objects so I can parse them, but I don't know how. How can I achieve this?

If the they're always comma delimited, would it be possible to wrap the string in [] characters... then you could simply run JSON.parse?

does it really come like that? no [ at the beginning? is each chunk a self contained valid JSON string? or are those , really in the stream?

They are not comma delimited, they appear like json strings one followed by another like I showed. I do not know how they are delimited as they come from another application. The only information I know is that it sends a stream of data. I modified the output removing the commas

Edited
To handle streamed JSON data, use TextDecoder to assemble chunks into a string  Look for delimiters (e.g., }\n{) to identify complete JSON objects split the string at these points and parse each segment with JSON.parse()
Server-Side:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/large-json', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        const jsonObject = JSON.stringify({ productName: `item${i}`, code: `CODE-${i}` });
        res.write(jsonObject + '\n');  // Separate objects with a newline
    }

    res.end();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

Client-Side :
const getProductData = async (url: string) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const reader = response.body?.getReader();

        let decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let partialData = '';

        if (!reader) throw new Error("Stream reader not available");

        while (true) {
            const { value, done } = await reader.read();
            if (done) break;

            partialData += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });

            let lines = partialData.split('\n');
            partialData = lines.pop()||'';  

            for (let line of lines) {
                if (line.trim()) {
                    try {
                        const jsonObject = JSON.parse(line);
                        console.log(jsonObject);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error("JSON parsing error: ", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (partialData.trim()) {
            try {
                const jsonObject = JSON.parse(partialData);
                console.log(jsonObject);
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("JSON parsing error in final chunk: ", e);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("Error ", e);
    }
};
getProductData("http://localhost:3000/large-json");


I do not want to all the data since the data could be megabytes of data. As the json data becomes available, I want to parse it as json objects and add it to the chunks, so that I can display it in chunks of json data, otherwise I will run out of memory. I also get an error  SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1 (line 1 column 2)

Sorry for the confusion I’ve updated the solution to efficiently handle and parse JSON data in chunks

Cheers! Really appreciated

Even if the application sends chunks that consist of exactly one JSON string each, the stream that comes out of the text decoder may concatenate several of the sent chunks into one chunk that is seen by the reader.
If the JSON strings were huge, it could happen that even one of them is split into two chunks seen by the reader. The solution below assumes that this is not the case (in other words: the application streams many small JSON strings, not one huge).
With this assumption, the code below splits each chunk seen by the reader at those positions where a closing brace is followed by (whitespace and) an opening brace. This is sufficient if each JSON string is just a productName/code object, as indicated in your question. If the JSON strings are more complex, the splitting may need to be adapted.


(async function() {
  const reader = (await fetch("https://httpbin.org/stream/10")).body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).getReader();
  while (true) {
    const {
      value,
      done
    } = await reader.read();
    console.log("new chunk read, done =", done);
    for (const v of value.split(/(?<=\})\s*(?=\{)/))
      console.log(JSON.parse(v).id);
    if (done) return;
  }
})();



Depending on network conditions, the 10 chunks of JSON sent by the application may give rise to 2 chunks (plus an empty one) seen by the reader.

The strings are about 100 per chunk returned by the reader.read() so I want to process them by adding 100 json objects. The above did not really give me the expected number of json objects as there were \n in most of the

If the splitting did not work, please give an example of where it went wrong. A line break in the JSON string can never be a split position, unless it comes between } and {.
